# SSL Certificate Verification Failure in WolframAlpha Python

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib, wolframalpha

So I'm currently trying to make a search engine that compiles data from multiple different databases and search engines, and everything has worked up until I tried to add the WolframAlpha API. When I try to run the WolframAlpha section of the code, it gives me about 20million lines of errors, but the most prominent ones seem to be:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)>
```

and

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)
```

The relevant code is the standard script for WolframAlpha Python queries:

```
import wolframalpha
def wolframSearch():
    client = wolframalpha.Client('wolfram-apikey')
    query = input("Please Input Wolfram Query: ")
    res = client.query(query)
    output = next(res.results).text
    print(output)

wolframSearch()
```

I'm currently using Python version 3.8 and I've already checked that the versions of all of the relevant modules and software

Comment: are you using a proxy?

Comment: @Mogi not as far as I am aware and I don't think the router has any firewalls or other restrictions that would get in the way of python

Comment: can you enter wolframalpha through your browser?

Comment: @Mogi yes I can and I can use all the tools fine, its just SSL certificate verification with python. I think its an error with urllib because when I tried to use my old data scraper script it threw up the same errors

Comment: because of the reasons you have mentioned I strongly believe you (or someone else) have installed another certificate on you computer and this is the reason it says it's a self signed certificate. try running the code on another computer it worked for me.

Comment: and make sure your browser doesn't tells you about certificate errors you ignores